# Object object is displaying in Node--red webpage

Tags: node-red

Inject o/p of the function node into html template using node red

**This is my flow**

```
 [
{"id":"b9787755.ece25",
"type":"http in",
"z":"77c9615d.84a36",
"name":"httpin",
"url":"/rand",
"method":"get",
"upload":false,
"swaggerDoc":"",
"x":210,
"y":220,
"wires":[["413c2211.ae5254"]]
},
{
"id":"116ae20e.efc5a6",
"type":"template",
"z":"77c9615d.84a36",
"name":"",
"field":"payload",
"fieldType":"msg",
"format":"handlebars",
"syntax":"mustache",
"template":"Hello Random - {{ payload}}",
"x":540,
"y":260,
"wires":[["6e6cb7b7.a71f7"]]},
{"id":"6e6cb7b7.a71f7",
"type":"http response",
"z":"77c9615d.84a36",
"name":"http response",
"x":708,
"y":217.00003051757812,
"wires":[]
},
{
"id":"53ef12d8.fa353c",
"type":"inject",
"z":"77c9615d.84a36",
"name":"Inject1",
"topic":"Topic1",
"payload":"hello world",
"payloadType":"str",
"repeat":"2",
"crontab":"",
"once":true,
"onceDelay":"2",
"x":120,
"y":100,
"wires":[["413c2211.ae5254"]]
},
{
"id":"413c2211.ae5254",
"type":"function",
"z":"77c9615d.84a36",
"name":"Random Fn",
"func":"var context=\"\"\ncontext = \"hi\"+msg.payload.toString()+\"hi\"\nmsg.payload=context\nreturn msg\n",
"outputs":1,
"noerr":0,
"x":470,
"y":140,
"wires":[["5b901ff7.344e3",
"116ae20e.efc5a6"]]},{"id":"5b901ff7.344e3",
"type":"debug",
"z":"77c9615d.84a36",
"name":"Debug1",
"active":true,
"tosidebar":true,
"console":false,
"tostatus":false,
"complete":"payload",
"x":679.0000610351562,
"y":154,
"wires":[]
}
]
```

Comment: Have you thought about it?

Comment: @Akheloes If I assign any string to msg payload it is working fine... But if I assign injected value to msg object it is not working

Comment: I am new to node red so kindly help me with this

Comment: Http in is supposed to serve static content, when you call the link "node-red-server/rand" the msg object is not defined, hence the issue, what are you trying to do ?

Comment: I want to send accelerometer sensor data to node red websocket listener then I want to pass the sensor data to html template

Comment: In debug node it is showing fyn but when I open the browse it does not showing properly

Comment: Did you consider using an HTTP request to send the data ?

Comment: @Akheloes thank you very much now it's working fyn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it sounds like you want to POST your sensor data to a node-red flow? Whenever you start a flow with an `http in` node, you need to end that flow with an `http response` (**not** `http request` -- that is for calling out to another http endpoint). You also need to make sure you reuse the msg object and retain the req/res headers.

Since the output of your function is showing the correct string in the debug node, you just need to return that same string with the `http response` node. In the example above, where you want to type the url `http://servername/rand` into your browser, your `http in` node would have to be configured for `GET` requests. In this case, the output payload from the `http in` node would be empty, so your function will not do what you expect. But if you configure it for `POST` requests, then you will need to send your data programatically, not from a browser.

In the end, it sounds like you want two flows -- a `POST` listener that takes the incoming sensor data and stores it in a database (or somewhere), and a `GET` listener that takes the incoming req params, builds a SQL Select... statement, and returns the query results. For the `POST` flow, even if you don't return any data, you still need to respond with a 200 OK code.

Comment: Than you so much @Steve

Comment: Yuvi, if this has answered your question, please accept it as the solution... if not, then what problem are you still having?